# Recovered File has weird numbers

Tags: file-recovery

I have a recovered file from which I accidentally deleted using command line. Unfortunately one of the file content is what I'm not expecting to see.

Here's the content of that file.

[image]

Is it still possible to recover this file?

Comment: Can you provide additional details on which commands exactly have you used to recover this file via command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely, no.  Assuming the file was recovered with the proper extension and the default reader cannot open the file, then the contents of that file were overwritten.

FYI, those "weird numbers" are hexadecimal, the *slightly* more human readable form of binary.

Recovery programs will try to restore a file, since its location is in the File Allocation Table (FAT).  However, this doesnt mean the file was not overwritten.  There is no guarantee the file has not been damaged.

Unfortunately, deleting through the command line does not move a file to the Recycle Bin.  It simply marks the file as deleted.  It is always safer to delete a file through Windows, which will use the Recycle Bin.

And as always, make backups.